# Windows Azure - Free Trial

Tags: azure, sms, verification

I want to try, [windows azure free trial](https://account.windowsazure.com/signup?offer=ms-azr-0018p&wa=wsignin1.0) but our country didn't listed in SMS supported countries, so could not receive any of verification using phone number, is there any workaround?

Comment: -1 Off topic. Not really a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the FAQ's https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/faq/

It lists the countries that Azure is available in.